# Horizontal scroll below 1000 width

Tags: css, background, scroll

Am struggling for a few days now, and I was reached a solution which does not seem to work.

Anyway, what I am trying to do is to 'lock' the screen when somebody drags the window **smaller than 1000 px in width**. What do I mean by that, well, a **horizontal scrollbar must appear and the background image must stop resizing and the text stop shifting**. The background must become horizontal scrollable when reaching below 1000px as well as the text.

Hope can somebody can help me out, trying for two days now :s

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Hup</title>


<style type="text/css">
html{

    background: url(jup.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    min-width:500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:auto 580px;
    background-position: center 120px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='jup.png',     sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='jup.png', sizingMethod='scale');
}

#menu {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:80px;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:absolute;
right:20px;
}
.menu_container {
    width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    height:100px;
}
#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:720px;
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.bottom_container {
    width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    height:100px;

}
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;

}
body {
    min-width:1024px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="menu">
<div class="container">
Text here
</div>

</div>
<div id="bottom">
<div class="container">
Text here
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your html min- and max-width conflict with the width you have set for the html tag. Try to remove these settings.

Comment: It's rare to see the HTML tag styled as you have it. I'd change that to body {} and add Adam's solution from below.

Comment: If I only keep the min width in the html tag, or only in the body tag, the background still won't slide along, the text does, but the background doesn't...

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
body { min-width: 1000px; }
```

Comment: I am having this in my body tag right now... Even if I remove the min width in the html tag, the background is still not sliding along.. :s

Comment: Put your background image on your body (in your CSS) not your <html> tag. Remember, you're setting the min-width of the body, not of the <html> tag.