# How to make a window scroll horizontally when resized under 1000px

Tags: javascript, css, resize

I would like to make the browser window scroll horizontally when its width reaches 1000px.

JavaScript or CSS answer appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal scroll below 1000 width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486016/horizontal-scroll-below-1000-width)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be complicated:

```
.my-page-wrapper-element {min-width: 1000px; overflow: auto;}
```

Comment: What is `scroll: auto`? Do you mean `overflow`?

Comment: Oops. Too busy today. Yep.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
body { min-width: 1000px; }
```

???

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment, I think you can just put a  in the document and make it 1000px wide?

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">Hello World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#wrap{
    width:1000px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Y9Gm/

Comment: assuming that my laptop has a resolution of 1400px. I would like the window scrolls horizontally when I resizing under 1000px

Comment: I don't think you need media queries for this.

Comment: @Mathletics - I agree, I updated my answer, your answer is still better however, so I've +1'd it :)